# i have to pass multiple variables in form_open() in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i want to pass two variables in view page

my code.

```
$user=$this->session->userdata('username');
$fyear=$this->session->userdata('fyear');
echo form_open('Erp_c/usercustomerinsert/'.$user);?>
```

I want to pass the other variable `$fyear too..`

I tried this.

```
<?php
 $user=$this->session->userdata('username');
 $fyear=$this->session->userdata('fyear');
 echo form_open('Erp_c/usercustomerinsert/'.$user.$fyear);?>
```

value is not getting.

Comment: what do you mean value not getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    $user=$this->session->userdata('username');
    $fyear=$this->session->userdata('fyear');
    $add = $user.$fyear;
    echo form_open('Erp_c/usercustomerinsert/'.$add);

?>
```

and in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');
```

Comment: @ShaifulIslam this is the difference `$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');` and `$add` in form

Comment: how do you know he did not load helpers?he said his first code works but 2nd does not works which has no relation with helpers.If his first works means he loaded helpers.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it using by using hidden variable

```
$user=$this->session->userdata('username');
$fyear=$this->session->userdata('fyear');

$attributes = array('user' => $user, 'fyear' => $fyear);

echo form_open('Erp_c/usercustomerinsert/','', $attributes);
```

The above code make you form like

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/Erp_c/usercustomerinsert/">
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="user_VALUE" />
<input type="hidden" name="fyear" value="fyear_VALUE" />
```